# Calling a Stored Procedure From SSIS

Tags: ssis

Im trying to call the procedure with this form.

EXEC dbo.sp_consulta param

In parameters mapping i have this variable: "param".

In the variable that is holding the parameter im assigning int16 as the type but for the parameter type there is no int16, so I'm using short or signed. The error I'm getting is this:

error converting data type nvarchar to int

Comment: I'm not clear on what the variable types are on both sides of the call. Can you post the declaration of the parameters of your stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing this from a SQL task the correct format would be `EXEC dbo.sp_consulta ?`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx